# Issue with AsyncTask, when the onPostExecute is called?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem with OnPOstExecute of an AsyncTask, it works perfectly, but if the application some how stop, then a msg that generate a notification that opens the Activity that runs the AsyncTask, but the OnPOstExecute is never called.

My doubt is: why OnPOstExecute doesn't work when I try to open the Activity from a Notification if the application is closed.

Code:

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ...
               try{
                    loadListTask = new LoadListTask();
                    loadListTask.execute();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG,"ERRO: "+e.getMessage());
                 }
      }


public void loadListView() {
        messagesDb = useful.buscarMessagesDb(this);
        ArrayList<Message> messageListViews = new ArrayList<Message>();
        int messagesDbSize = messagesDb.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < messagesDbSize; i++) {
            if (((messagesDb.get(i).idFrom == myId) && (messagesDb.get(i).idTo == idContact)) || 
                    ((messagesDb.get(i).idFrom == idContact) && (messagesDb.get(i).idTo == myId))) {
                Message message = new Message(messagesDb.get(i).idFrom, messagesDb.get(i).idTo, 
                        messagesDb.get(i).dt, messagesDb.get(i).mensagem, messagesDb.get(i).confirm,
                        messagesDb.get(i).idWeb);           
                messageListViews.add(message);
            } else {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Essa mensagem não é pra esse contato!!!");
            }
        }
            listChat.setAdapter(null);
            pref.edit().putBoolean("isUpdate", false).commit();
            AdapterMessageListView adapterMessageListView = new AdapterMessageListView(myId, idContact, 
                    getApplicationContext(), messageListViews); 
            listChat.setAdapter(adapterMessageListView);
            listChat.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            listChat.setSelection(listChat.getCount());
    }

private class LoadListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            return "list";
        }
            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() {
                Log.d(TAG,"PREEXECUTE");

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                Log.d(TAG,"PostExecute");
                loadListView();
                loadListTask = new LoadListTask();
                loadListTask.execute();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
```

Message:

```
02-25 14:05:42.396: D/Chat(20663): doInBackground
02-25 14:05:42.396: W/MessageQueue(20663): Handler{40532ad8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
02-25 14:05:42.396: W/MessageQueue(20663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{40532ad8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. >The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Once your application is closed, there is no UI thread anymore. That is why the log shows the statement 'on a dead thread'.

Comment: Imagine this situation, the user have just turn on the cellphone, and I sent a message for him, the message generate a notification in the cell phone, when the user press that notification , it opens the Activity  and the onCreate of that Activity initiate the AsyncTask.

Comment: That is a valid use-case and one I use myself in one of my Apps.
With GCM (Google Cloud Message) you send a message to the App. In onMessage() I check if the activity is active. If it is, I start an AsyncTask and if it is not I generate a notification and set a flag. 
Next time the app is made active, I check the flas and if needed trigger an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
// workaround for http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915
try {
        Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

http://oldcodemonkey.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/android-sending-message-to-handler-on.html
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20915